# Merging multiple CSV files without headers being repeated (using Python)

Tags: python, csv

I am a beginner with Python. I have multiple CSV files (more than 10), and all of them have same number of columns. I would like to merge all of them into a single CSV file, where I will not have headers repeated.

So essentially I need to have just the first row with all the headers and from then I need all the rows from all CSV files merged. How do I do this?

Here's what I tried so far.

```
import glob
import csv



with open('output.csv','wb') as fout:
    wout = csv.writer(fout,delimiter=',') 
    interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv") 
    for filename in interesting_files: 
        print 'Processing',filename 
    # Open and process file
        h = True
        with open(filename,'rb') as fin:
                fin.next()#skip header
        for line in csv.reader(fin,delimiter=','):
                wout.writerow(line)
```

Comment: I have updated what I tried so far. @MarcB

Comment: so what's the problem? looks like it should work, other than not preserving the header line of the first file.

Comment: The indentation on for line in csv.reader(fin,delimiter=','):  looks incorrect.

Comment: Instead of the last `for` loop, you could use the line-liner `wout.writerows(csv.reader(fin,delimiter=','))` to copy the remainder of each `fin` file.

Comment: important! change `wb` to `w` to avoid `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` error messages.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While I think that the best answer is the one from @valentin, you can do this without using `csv` module at all:

```
import glob

interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv") 

header_saved = False
with open('output.csv','wb') as fout:
    for filename in interesting_files:
        with open(filename) as fin:
            header = next(fin)
            if not header_saved:
                fout.write(header)
                header_saved = True
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)
```

Comment: @m.wasowski This one worked, but all that it simply does is to merge the files. Even the headers are merged. I have 10 CSV files all of which have same headers. So essentially I get the header rows 10 times in the output file with this code. Any modifications suggested?

Comment: my bad, I moved reading header into `if` block unecessary. see fixed version; @PadraicCunningham leftover from other idea, fixed, thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work if csv files have title lines on more than one line

Answer (score 37):

If you are on  a linux system:

```
head -1 director/one_file.csv > output.csv   ## writing the header to the final file
tail -n +2  director/*.csv >> output.csv  ## writing the content of all csv starting with second line into final file
```

Comment: I needed to add '-q' (--quiet) to the tail command to avoid extra text being included in the resulting file.

Comment: as per @ElMesa, I had to use "tail **-q** -n +2  *.csv" on Windows

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre you can tune the arguments of head and tail to use/skip x lines

Comment: yes, but I mean: python csv module/pandas are able to properly detect a line. No need to know how many lines there are. I admin that if you want to do that with a known title, you can do it (even if it's not a generic solution)

Answer (score 8):

If you dont mind the overhead, you could use pandas which is shipped with common python distributions. If you plan do more with speadsheet tables, I recommend using pandas rather than trying to write your own libraries.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
df_list = []
for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)

full_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Just a little more on pandas. Because it is made to deal with spreadsheet like data, it knows the first line is a header. When reading a CSV it separates the data table from the header which is kept as metadata of the `dataframe`, the standard datatype in pandas. If you concat several of these `dataframes` it concatenates only the dataparts if their headers are the same. If the headers are not the same it fails and gives you an error. Probably a good thing in case your directory is polluted with CSV files from another source.

Another thing: I just added `sorted()` around the `interesting_files`. I assume your files are named in order and this order should be kept. I am not sure about glob, but the `os` functions are not necessarily returning files sorted by their name.

Comment: I tried this, but I get the following error: Import Error: No module named Pandas.

Comment: it seems pandas is not installed. Try in the terminal `pip install pandas`. If you are using a simple python installation, you might benefit from installing a python distribution such as anaconda (http://continuum.io/downloads) to start with the most common packages installed.

Comment: thank you so much! I will try pandas. Looks like it should make my job easier.

Comment: Careful here, I just debugged a script for an hour because glob decided to format my strings as integers and dropped a zero-pad from a bunch of my strings.

Comment: you mean you got the filenames in the wrong order from `sorted`?

Comment: I think it was an issue with SublimeText, because I tried the same script today and it didn't cast them. Must have been a value in cache or something. Ignore my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is almost working, but the issues are:

- you're opening the file for reading but closing it before writing the rows.
- you're never writing the title. You have to write it once
- Also you have to *exclude* output.csv from the "glob" else the output is also in input!

Here's the corrected code, passing the csv object direcly to `csv.writerows` method for shorter & faster code. Also writing the title from the first file to the output file.

```
import glob
import csv

output_file = 'output.csv'
header_written = False

with open(output_file,'w',newline="") as fout:  # just "wb" in python 2
    wout = csv.writer(fout,delimiter=',')
    # filter out output
    interesting_files = [x for x in glob.glob("*.csv") if x != output_file]
    for filename in interesting_files:
        print('Processing {}'.format(filename))
        with open(filename) as fin:
            cr = csv.reader(fin,delmiter=",")
            header = cr.next() #skip header
            if not header_written:
                wout.writerow(header)
                header_written = True
            wout.writerows(cr)
```

Note that solutions using raw line-by-line processing miss an important point: if the header is multi-line, they miserably fail, botching the title line/repeating part of it several time, efficiently corrupting the file.

csv module (or pandas, too) handle those cases gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is wrong, you need to put the loop inside the with block. You can also pass the file object to writer.writerows.

```
import csv
with open('output.csv','wb') as fout:
    wout = csv.writer(fout)
    interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
    for filename in interesting_files:
        print 'Processing',filename
        with open(filename,'rb') as fin:
                next(fin) # skip header
                wout.writerows(fin)
```

Comment: it is incorrect because you're not reading inputs as csv, but as raw lines