# Automate file download from web with login and multiple subrouts for each file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I gotta download 250 csv files in 250 separate webpages within the same domain that requires a login.

Each csv file contains data for a certain date each  located in a webpage(in the same domain) for that specific date.

So for  3 dates the links to download 3 cvs files after the login is successful look like this:
https://app.chartmetric.com/charts/spotify/daily?type=regional&region=global&date=2019-01-03
https://app.chartmetric.com/charts/spotify/daily?type=regional&region=global&date=2019-01-02
https://app.chartmetric.com/charts/spotify/daily?type=regional&region=global&date=2019-01-01

After clicking in a box that looks the same within each of this webs i get each time a cvs file, for each of this webs the cvs file names would be the following.
SPOTIFY DAILY GLOBAL CHART - TOP 200 (2019-01-03).csv
SPOTIFY DAILY GLOBAL CHART - TOP 200 (2019-01-02).csv
SPOTIFY DAILY GLOBAL CHART - TOP 200 (2019-01-01).csv

Please help me out to automate the process to download all this 250 csv files or maybe even make it so that i can define the range of dates wanted for download to be read from another csv file.

the click button for beginning the download for each csv file in each date specific webpage looks like this

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I can I lazily read multiple JSON values from a file/stream in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886283/how-i-can-i-lazily-read-multiple-json-values-from-a-file-stream-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335474/merging-multiple-csv-files-without-headers-being-repeated-using-python

Comment: Have you done any work about that?